# Should this post be moved to server fault?

Tags: discussion

I posted this question:  [Adding employee to directory](https://superuser.com/questions/1005787/adding-employee-to-directory)

I can see that Super User and Server Fault have questions regarding PBX and VOIP, does this question belong here?

Comment: I'm not sure what site this would be on topic for (it's not clear to me that ServerFault is the place for it), but I'm pretty sure it's very much on the fringe of what would be on-topic for SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Server Fault has accepted questions about PBX systems in the past. However, the Server Fault community has little experience with them, as most system administrators do not also manage traditional phone systems, and I think it is unlikely to get an answer.